# Install HAProxy on RedHat 6.6

Tags: redhat, haproxy

I have a fresh install of Red Hat 6.6, and I want to install HAProxy on. I've read that it's now fully supported, but I haven't been able to install it. Running `yum search haproxy` returns no matches. I've found plenty of articles saying I need to install EPEL, but alas, it's been removed. How do I install HAProxy on Red Hat 6.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

haproxy is in the  RHEL Server Load Balancer (v6 for 64-bit x86_64) `rhel-lb-for-rhel-6-server-rpms` channel. You'll need to add this channel to your server.

Comment: I was on Rackspace and couldn't add that channel without a subscription to I just switched to Fedora 20.